# Python: Iterate through object executing code both at certain places and also at end

Tags: python, list, code-duplication

Here is some samplecode to explain:

```
outputText=""
counter=0
for obj in specialObjects:
    if (obj.id < 400) or (obj.name.startswith("he")) or (obj.deliberateBreak==True):
        print "The object %s is causing a section break."%obj.details
        outputText = outputText.rjust(80)
        open("file%d.txt"%counter,"w").write(outputText)
        outputText=""
    outputText+=obj.shortValue()
# THIS CODE IS DUPLICATED
outputText = outputText.rjust(80)
open("file%d.txt"%counter,"w").write(outputText)
```

What I need to do is iterate over a list of these special objects and check a few different conditions each time. If any of the conditions are met (as seen here) then I need to take the current output buffer, write it to a file, then start a new output buffer and keep processing.

The problem here is the code duplication. Notice how the two lines (outputText= and open) are duplicated. If I fail to put in the second set of lines, the last set of objects will be processed but their output will never be written.

I can think of two possible solutions to prevent the code duplication. Both of them seem slightly inelegant, so I was wondering if there was an even better way.

1) Wrap the code that would be repeated in a function.

```
outputText=""
counter=0
for obj in specialObjects:
    if (obj.id < 400) or (obj.name.startswith("he")) or (obj.deliberateBreak==True):
        print "The object %s is causing a section break."%obj.details
        counter = writeData(outputText)
        outputText=""
    outputText+=obj.shortValue()
writeData(outputText,counter)

def writeData(outputText,counter):
    outputText = outputText.rjust(80)
    open("file%d.txt"%counter,"w").write(outputText)
    return counter+1
```

2) Use a numeric for loop instead, and count to one higher than the length of the object list; use that value as a flag to mean "write, but now exit":

```
outputText=""
counter=0
for obj in range(len(specialObjects))+1:
    if (obj = len(specialObjects)) or (specialObjects[obj].id < 400) or (specialObjects[obj].name.startswith("he")) or (specialOejcts[obj].deliberateBreak==True):
        print "The object %s is causing a section break."%specialObjects[obj].details
        outputText = outputText.rjust(80)
        open("file%d.txt"%counter,"w").write(outputText)
        outputText=""
        if (obj==len(specialObjects)):
            break 
    outputText+=specialObjects[obj].shortValue()
```

If I had to choose one, I'd probably pick #2, but this could end up creating some weird edge cases with the 'if' statement if any more complex boolean logic ever needs to be used.

Is there an even cleaner or more "Pythonic" way to accomplish this without code duplication?

Thanks!

Comment: You only change `counter` in the middle example. Should the first and last versions really open the same file multiple times and then just discarding it without closing, or are they missing some code?

Comment: This might be a duplicate of [Avoiding repeat of code after loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11149997/avoiding-repeat-of-code-after-loop)

Answer (score 2):

When I find myself writing code like this, where I'm iterating over a collection and repeating code after the end of the loop, I usually take it as a sign that I'm not iterating over the right thing.

In this case, you're iterating over a list of objects. But what you *really* want to iterate over, I think, is a list of *groups* of objects. That's what [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) is useful for.

Your code has a lot going on, so I'm going to use a simplified example to illustrate how you can get rid of that duplicate code. Say, for (a very contrived) example, that I have a list of things like this:

```
things = ["apples", "oranges", "pears", None, 
          "potatoes", "tomatoes", None,
          "oatmeal", "eggs"]
```

This is a list of objects. Looking carefully, there are several groups of objects delimited by `None` (note that you'd typically represent `things` as a nested list, but let's ignore that for the purpose of the example). My goal is to print out each group on a separate line:

```
apples, oranges, pears
potatoes, tomatoes
oatmeal, eggs
```

Here's the "ugly" way of doing this:

```
current_things = []
for thing in things:
    if thing is None:
        print ", ".join(current_things)
        current_things = []
    else:
        current_things.append(thing)

print ", ".join(current_things)
```

As you can see, we have that duplicated `print` after the loop. Nasty!

Here's the solution using `groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby

for key, group in groupby(things, key=lambda x: x is not None):
    if key:
        print ", ".join(group)
```

`groupby` takes an iterable (`things`) and a key function. It looks at each element of the iterable and applies the key function. When the key changes value, a new group is formed. The result is an iterator that returns `(key, group)` pairs.

In this case, we'll use the check for `None` to be our key function. That's why we need the `if key:`, since there will be groups of size one corresponding to the `None` elements of our list. We'll just skip those.

As you can see, `groupby` allows us to iterate over the things we *really* want to iterate over: *groups* of objects. This is more natural for our problem, and the code simplifies as a result. It looks like your code is very similar to the above example, except that your key function will check the various properties of the object (`obj.id < 400 ...`). I'll leave the implementation details up to you...

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to do it with a sentinel object. It's similar to your second option, but cleaner I think.

```
for obj in itertools.chain(specialObjects, [None]):
    if (obj is None) or (obj.id < 400) or (obj.name.startswith("he")) or (obj.deliberateBreak==True):
        outputText = outputText.rjust(80)
        open("file%d.txt"%counter,"w").write(outputText)
        if obj is None: break
        print "The object %s is causing a section break."%obj.details
        outputText=""
    outputText+=obj.shortValue()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could separate the code that breaks up the objects into a generator so that the later processing step does not need to be duplicated.

```
def yield_sections(specialObjects):
    outputText = ''
    for obj in specialObjects:
        if (obj.id < 400) or (obj.name.startswith("he")) or (obj.deliberateBreak==True):
            yield outputText
            outputText = ''
        outputText += obj.shortValue()
    if outputText:
        yield outputText


for counter, outputText in enumerate(yield_sections(specialObjects)):
    outputText = outputText.rjust(80)
    open("file%d.txt"%counter,"w").write(outputText)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution if you use iterators,  `next` can give a special value at the end. So you can use a sentinel to check if your current object is a true one or if you finished iteration.

Try something like this:

```
outputText=""
counter=0
ending = object()
it = iter(specialObjects)
while True:
    obj = next(it, ending)
    if obj is ending or obj.id < 400 or obj.name.startswith("he") or obj.deliberateBreak:
        outputText = outputText.rjust(80)
        open("file%d.txt"%counter,"w").write(outputText)
        counter += 1
        outputText=""
    if obj is ending:
        break
    outputText+=obj.shortValue()
```